# How do you create a socket in a server and emit

Tags: node.js, sockets

How do you create a socket in node with socket.io and emit to it.

The idea is that i am getting data from a twilio from the server and with this data i want to send it to 
an ios app

I Have tried

```
var server = require('http').Server(router);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    router.post('/respond', function(req, res) {
        var result_From;
        var result_Digits;
        res.header('Content-Type','text/xml').send(SAY_TO_USER);

        result_From = req.body.From;
        result_Digits = req.body.Digits;

        console.log( result_From + " typed: " + result_Digits);

    io.emit('values changed', 'data');

        });

io.on('values changed', function(){ 
    console.log('hello')
 });
server.listen(8080);
```

what i want to do in that route is when a request comes in, it changes both result_Digits and result_From so i want to be able to emit a socket when the value changes so i can use it on a mac application.

Cheers

Comment: Where is the socket.io code you've tried?

Comment: @xShirase i just edited my post sorry

Comment: A client has to connect before you can send data to it.  Without a connection, there is nothing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need your clients to connect to your socket, usually in your client html document :

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script> 
    var socket = io.connect(); 
    socket.on('values changed', function(values){
     //do something with values
    });
</script>
```

Then you can use in your app :

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('values changed', function(){ 
    console.log('hello')
 });
});
```