# how to use socket.io in express route?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using Express 4 (created with express 4 generator) with Socket.io but I can't figure out how to use SocKet.io in Express routes(like socket.emit()).

here is my code

```
app.js

======================================================================
// get all the tools we need
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var passport = require('passport');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongooseConnection = require('./database/db.js');
var flash = require('connect-flash');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');// set up ejs for templating

// app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));

require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

// required for passport
app.use(session({
    secret: 'random_secret_key',
    store: new mongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: mongooseConnection
    }),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());// persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session


// set up our express application
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());

//Serve static content for the app from the "public" directory in the application directory.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// routes ======================================================================
var index = require('./routes/index');
var api = require('./routes/api');
// var users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api', api);
// app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

for create server app is needed and socket.io need server instanse

server.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('ultimate-tic-tac-toe:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

require ('../resources/assets/js/socket.io')(server);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

socket.io.js

```
module.exports = function (server) {
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        console.log('a user connected');

        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            console.log('user disconnected');
        });

    });

};
```

i want to use socket.emit() in routes but have no ideea how to pas io object to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a socket in a server and emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198808/how-do-you-create-a-socket-in-a-server-and-emit)